# create a EXE file using netbeans c++ programing

Tags: c++, netbeans

I wrote a C++ program using Netbeans.

I can run the program while using Netbeans, but I don't know how to create a EXE file. I usually use dev C++ and it creates an EXE file automatically.

Comment: AFAIK, just building it should generate the ".exe" file.

Comment: @JamesRoot but where to find it?